# Необходимо 1 запросом вставить строку а если такой ключ уже имеется тогда заменить

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица формата
name, param_1, param_2, param_3, ... ,param_n
В данной таблице нет поля id или другого автоинкремента.
И поле name является уникальным ключом.

Нужно в один запрос заменить все значения строки с данным ключом, если такого ключа нету тогда добавить строку.

Примечание - при замене не важно какие значения находятся в столбцах param_n.

Comment: используйте триггеры mysql

Comment: не совсем подходит для моей задачи.
Дополнительное уточнение.
запросы отправляются из нескольких программ с очень высокой частотой.

Comment: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) *заменить все значения строки с данным ключом, если такого ключа нету тогда добавить* Идеологически - наоборот. Добавить, а если при этом будет ошибка дублирования - обновить существующую запись.

Comment: @Akina спасибо, должно подойти)

Answer (score 0):

Метод INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE помог.